# What is the source for not being afraid of ayin hara because Yosef Hatzadik sustained the whole world we are all considered his descendants?

Tags: sources-mekorot, yosef, ayin-hara-evil-eye

What is the source for not being afraid of ayin hara because we are all considered Yosef Hatzadik's descendants since he sustained the whole world in Mitzrayim (and ayin hara doesnt affect Yosef's offsprings)?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you believe that there is such a source?

Comment: I heard it in a shiur

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.20a.7

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.55b.12

Comment: @yoseflavi Can you [edit] that into the question (including any details about the shiur if you remember)?

Comment: י"ל דהלחש הוא כן ועי"ל דכל ישראל נקראו ע"ש יוסף דכתיב נוהג כצאן יוסף וגו' וק"ל  https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Berakhot.55b.7

Comment: https://youtu.be/NKUlGxNI07Q

Comment: @hazoriz nice song but doesnt really answer my question

Comment: @yoseflavi the rest of my links do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Berachos 55b:

> האי מאן דעייל למתא ודחיל מעינא בישא לנקוט זקפא דידא דימיניה בידא דשמאליה וזקפא דידא דשמאליה בידא דימיניה ולימא הכי אנא פלוני בר פלוני מזרעא דיוסף קאתינא דלא שלטא ביה עינא בישא [...]
>
> This man who goes to a city and is worried of Ayin Hara, he should stick his right thumb in his left hand, and he should stick his left thumb in his right hand, and he should say thus: “I, Ploni bar Ploni, am of the offspring of Yosef, over whom Ayin Hara doesn’t rule [Gemara continues with sources here]

The Maharsha (h/t hazoriz - I’m clearly not one, catching this question over a month late) [asks](https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Berakhot.55b.7) how one can be so sure that he’s descended from Yosef. In other, similar cases, one can say that there was a tradition in their family, but in this Gemara, a general case, you can’t make that assumption. His (second) answer:

> ועי"ל דכל ישראל נקראו ע"ש יוסף דכתיב נוהג כצאן יוסף וגו' וק"ל:
>
> There is to further say that all Jews are called Yosef, as it says, “Who leads Yosef like sheep.”

That passuk is Tehillim 80:2. Guess how Rashi there explains why we’re called Yosef?

> וכל ישראל נקראים על שם יוסף לפי שהוא פירנסם וכלכלם בימי הרעב:
>
> All Jews are called Yosef because he sustained and fed them during the days of famine.